# Trace clearance for 500V insulation test

Tags: pcb, high-voltage, trace, clearance

Part of my job is to measure insulation resistance of cables using a tester, such as a Fluke 1587. We measure insulation resistance at 500 VDC. We have to measure insulation resistance pin to pin and some of the cables have 56 pins, which gives us 1540 combinations! We currently use a breakout box and have to move the probes manually one by one through all the combinations. We have a couple boxes we made where we use switches to tie the pins to one of two channels which allows us to hold the meter at 500V in two test points while we switch through each pin, checking one channel against the other. This significantly reduces the amount of time to check cables, but producing them is a pain. Currently they are made by hand soldering wires and daisy chaining the switches together. I would like to replace this with a PCB with switches mounted on the board.

My question is in regards to the trace clearance I would need to not effect the insulation resistance reading. Most of the information I could gather from online searches for high voltage trace clearance reference to IPC standards which are needed for safety. Since my application is not safety related nor will cause damage to any equipment (cable is disconnected on both ends when testing), I don't need to worry about injury or component failure. I am assuming the solder mask can provide a decent amount of insulation resistance for this purpose, but I want to make sure before I send out a design that would cause false low insulation resistance reading because of the traces being to close. What would be the minimum clearance I could use and not have an effect on our readings? I am trying to keep size down since we need to ship these things around to different sites on top of all our other tools and equipment.

Thanks.

Edit:
Added pictures of project. The schematic shows enough detail of what I am building as well as a theory of operation for the test kit. The portion not shown is just a repetition of switches and test points.
The PCB has a minimum trace clearance rule set to 11 mils. It is the largest I can make it and still be able to route between the pins of the connector. Layout it nowhere near complete, but I figured I better find out the answer to my question before I go too far.
Snapshot of the 3d model provides a clearer picture of what it is I am working towards.

[image: Partial Schematic]
[image: PCB]
[image: Zoomed in PCB]
[image: 3d Model]

Comment: Post what you have, we can only take wild guesses at what you have done.  Typical solder mask has a voltage rating of about 500 V/mil.  Soldermask is thinner on the top corner of the copper trace, so may not be 1mil.  I'd rely on spacing rules.

Comment: The IPC safety rules are directly related to arcing and creepage.https://resources.altium.com/p/high-voltage-pcb-design-creepage-and-clearance-distance

Comment: In my application, safety is not an issue. The only high voltage source is an insulation meter used to check out cables that have been disconnected from all equipment. Standards usually have a margin of safety to account for variations of all conditions. If I followed IPC, it would require a trace separation of almost 100 mils. I don't even have that much clearance on the pins of the connector mounted on the PCB. I am trying to find out what kind of clearance I need so that our readings are over 100Mohms at 500V without trace clearance being a factor to decrease it.

Comment: you have a choice... follow the IPC and have a high chance of no problems or don't and potentially damage something or someone. Grow the board or use conformal coating

Comment: John thanks for the suggestion of conformal coating. My other thought was to bring the traces to internal layers. According to the standard, using internal traces, the minimum clearance is 1/10th of external. I am trying to keep the cost down, so maybe conformal coating is the way to go. Also, there is no risk of damaging equipment or harming anyone in my application. All electronics are disconnected from the cable under test and the insulation tester produces no more than a static shock to the skin. I was trying to see what I could get away without affecting our measurements.